Camera with heavy cable attached, how to mount it on a gimbal
The situation:
I have a 6s quadcopter with a takeoff weight of around 3-3.5 kg (excluding gimbal and camera). So far, I've been using a normal brushless gimbal (Tarot TL3T06) with an USB camera. A lightweight, self made USB cable ran from the camera to the companion computer.
Now, I'd like to switch to an Oak-T camera, which comes with PoE instead of USB connectivity.
A gimbal requires a well balanced camera with little movement resistance. It was already tedious to make my gimbal work with a USB cable connected to the camera, but a fully shielded PoE cable will make gimbal movement impossible.
My question:
How can I properly balance a camera with a heavy cable attached that provides a certain movement resistance on a GoPro scale gimbal? Did you ever have this problem? How did you tackle it?
What I tried so far:
I tried using a servo gimbal instead. The first problem here is that commercial servo gimbals don't seem to exist and I had to build my own. The second problem is that servos don't have the smooth movement curve of a bldc motor. My first tries were quite messy. I could try to add transmission to the servos, but this would take serious (and expensive) engineering efforts and I'd like to know my other option before going down that road.
